# Error en programa para saber cantidad de repeticiones de letra en palabra

Tags: c++

Ejercicio donde me piden crear una variable de tipo string con nombre text, una variable de tipo carácter de nombre lletra y una variable de tipo entero con nombre quantitat.

A continuación captura del canal de entrada una cadena y almacenala en la variable text, y capturar también un carácter y almacenarlo en la variable lletra.

A continuación, usar la función countAppearances para almacenar la variable quantitat el número de veces que la letra aparece en text. Una vez obtenido, muestra por pantalla el mensaje "Letter" + lletra + "appears" + quantitat + "times in the texto" + text.

Me da error sobretodo en la variable num y no sé si he resuelto bien el ejercicio con el for y si la función está bien declarada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int countApperances(string s, char c);

int countApperances(string s, char c)
{
  for(int i; i < s.length(); s += 1){
    int num = 0;
    if(s[i] == c){
      num += 1;
    }
    i+= 1;
  }
  return num;
}

int main(){
  string text;
  char lletra;
  int quantitat;
  cin >> text >> lletra;
  quantitat = countApperances(text, lletra);
  cout << "Letter " << lletra << " appears " << quantitat << " times in the next " << text; 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para contar la cantidad de elementos E en un contenedor C, puedes usar la función [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
// Cuenta la cantidad de E dentro de C
auto cantidad_e = std::count(C.begin(), C.end(), E);
```

Así que tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main() {
    std::string text;
    char lletra;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    std::cin >> lletra;

    int quantitat = std::count(text.begin(), text.end(), lletra);
    std::cout << "Letter '" << lletra
        << "' appears " << quantitat
        << " times in the text \"" << text << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBTsNADEXXmVN8hUVbqVSsm9IdO46QjTMxqdFkEiaOVAlxIBacogcLmUlp2dn@7/tbtn3/2Fg7TQ/irRtrxkG6QQNTezT3GbmmC6KneWjEK1oSv97g02SD1vv9bBDfQPmshcnsiQKcYw1UXIGG1YnndWqs@G1iN3/yPMHxePOYLGZ8jORVlBTPWKhu9LqOxl3FTTxgWbNjX8d6sd@XdqPicED@yqocsMpjt0Amy6KyAvU9UxiQtFviVYZKywPm4/TEKQplnshUR6TMS5/HiwPrGDyeCvM1TS8OFTmH@XWOYKWimvDeYRzADnZOoXD53qLtPHoKnJIjOnBbBaoIbywEkvPlZ/uvNvQL)</kbd>.

Si lo que quieres es implementar la función `countApperances`, tienes errores muy graves en tu implementación:

```
int countApperances(string s, char c)
{
  for(int i; i < s.length(); s += 1){
    int num = 0;
    if(s[i] == c){
      num += 1;
    }
    i+= 1;
  }
  return num;
}
```

La variable `num` sólo existe dentro del bucle `for` (una variable que aparezca entre llaves `{` y `}` sólo existe dentro de esas llaves):

```
int countApperances(string s, char c)
{
  for(int i; i < s.length(); s += 1){
    int num = 0;  // <--- 'num' empieza a existir aquí
    if(s[i] == c){
      num += 1;
    }
    i+= 1;
  } // <--- 'num' deja de existir aquí.
  return num; // <--- ¿Qué es 'num'? ¡eso no existe!
}
```

Te aconsejo lo siguiente:

1. Recibe la cadena como referencia constante:

   1. Evitarás una copia innecesaria.
   2. Dado que no vas a modificar la cadena, debe ser constante.
2. Crea el contador fuera del bucle.
3. Usa el bucle `for` de rango.

Siguiendo esos consejos, tu función `countApperances` podría parecerse a:

```
int countApperances(const std::string &s, char c)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (auto letra : s) {
        num += (letra == c);
    }
    return num;
}
```

El `for` de rango es más corto y fácil de escribir/leer, el recuento de letras usa un truco de C++: una comparación booleana (como comprobar si dos datos son iguales) da como resultado `true` o `false`, un valor booleano puede ser convertido implícitamente a entero siendo `0` el valor de `false` y `1` el valor de `true` así que la expresión:

```
num += (letra == c);
```

Sumará `1` cuando `letra` sea `c` y sumará `0` en caso contrario. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFNTgMxDIXXk1M8DRJMxSCx7p/Egh1H6MZNTRuUSYbEIyGhHogFp@jBSpIpbSGLKPH7/Ow4uu8ftlofjzfGaTtsGHPjowSmbqkuMbJbH4zs/gQTZtx2qZRxAu0HJ099z4Gc5tho76IgymY6HTncxhZ6RwF6oj4V0sp5buiwwOOsBF59QEODeFiWQJgiTjCyeWX2foFmFBeL5DTm7cseWIbgMjVT@7GrjoxrskV13Ynwh8xUVZqxxWx2ArYs1jhuykUb1xZ28iunCJbLc46qco33gZwYIUnv@D@FnN2e@IuLHwTzOeoXFuGAuzrfRkhVVVbuQMmEQkTRziVOMsR0HNP8IDsuLWJVF7KcM7KqV67OLZ6mkia8Px6fLdZkLdL3WYI2a9oQ3jyGCLbQqQqFw1eLzjv0FLhUzmjkbh1oTXhlQyDzcfhur86KfgA)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

varias cosas.
No has inicializado el i dentro del for. Ponle int i = 0;
Luego tu variable num es declarada dentro del for por ende cuando la retornas no puedes.
Saca tu variable num antes del for y ahi si funciona.
Ademas estas incrementando el string s.Eso causara que quede en loop.Por que lo agrandas en cada pasada. Debes cambiar es s+=1 por i++.
Tu codigo arreglado quedaria asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int countApperances(string s, char c);
int countApperances(string s, char c) {
    int apariciones = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
        if (s[i] == c)
            apariciones++;
    }
    return apariciones;
}
int main() {
    string text;
    char lletra;
    int quantitat;
    cin >> text >> lletra;
    quantitat = countApperances(text, lletra);
    cout << "Letter " << lletra << " appears " << quantitat << " times in the text " << text;
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos un abrazo.